# How to check MPEG2-TS "Continuity counter" form parse udp package

Tags: sockets, udp, mpeg2-ts

I am writing simple software to parse MPEG-TS stream

The following appears (udp package):

```
|_ Data           : 47004413273ac7..

|_ Data           : 470044113d1ab1..

|_ Data           : 4700441ffaad75..

|_ Data           : 4700441ddd42a8..

|_ Data           : 4700441485ac3a..

|_ Data           : 47004412ddfad2..

|_ Data           : 470044199e5822..


Len (188*7)

47 is Sync byte

044 is PID
```

But CC (cointinuity counter) is discontinuous (The eighth)

I want to check CC  to see if any packets were dropped

How do I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried? You know in which bits the CC field is located? Then just extract the CC field of consecutive TS packets and check if there are gaps.

Answer (score 0):

The Continuity Counter is a 4-bit length value located at the fourth byte from the packet's begining.

```
var cc = packet[3] & 0xf
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream#Packet